# Slick carousel - Using 3 slides with autoPlay=true causes slider-nav to act like there are 5 slides

Tags: javascript, html, css, carousel, slick.js

I am using Slick carousel and want to display 3 photos.  I have the 3 photos displayed in the bottom slider-nav pane.  Everything works as expected if I set slidesToShow=2 but when slidesToShow=3, which equals the total number of slides, the slide show displays 2 blank slides in the bottom nav even though it displays only the 3 main slides properly in the top  slider-for pane.

I realize if I turn autoplay=false then it works as expected, but I am showing before/during/after photos that I would like to auto loop thru, so customers can see all of the possible choices both in the nav slide while having it autoplay.

Any ideas how to get this to work?  I have seen mention that this should not be done, but it seems like a valuable use-case.  At least in my scenario.  I appreciate it!

```js
$('.slider-for').slick({
   slidesToScroll: 1,
   autoplay: true,
        autoplaySpeed: 4000,
   arrows: true,
   fade: true,
   asNavFor: '.slider-nav'  /* the child Nav bar */
  });
$('.slider-nav').slick({  /* the Nav display with thumbnails */
   slidesToShow: 3,
   slidesToScroll: 1,
   asNavFor: '.slider-for', /* the parent slider */
   dots: false,
   focusOnSelect: true,
   arrows: false,
   infinite: true
  });
```

```css
.main {
  font-family:Arial;
  width:500px;
  display:block;
  margin:0 auto;
}
.description {
    background: #fff;
    color: black;
    font-size: 20px;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 2%;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
}
.main h3 {
    background: #fff;
    color: black;
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 100px;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 2%;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
   

<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="slick/slick.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="slick/slicktheme.css"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
        </header>
        <main>
            <section class="main" align="center">
                 <div class="slider slider-for">
                     <div>
                        <img src="images/Siding/ChimneyRottingHoles.jpg"alt="Chimney with Hardboard Siding Rotting with holes">
                    </div>
                    <div>
                       <img src="images/Siding/Chimney New Flashing.jpg"
                     alt="Chimney replaced with new hardboard siding, new flashing and new cedar trim boards">
                    </div>
                    <div>
                       <img src="images/Siding/Chimney Cedar New Paint.jpg"
                     alt="Chimney and cedar trim repainted with Sherwin Williams Exterior Super Paint in a Satin finish">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="slider slider-nav">
                    <div class="description">Rotted Siding with Holes
                       <h3 style="background-image: url('images/Siding/Chimney Rotting Holes.jpg'); background-size: cover">
                    &nbsp;
                       </h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="description">New Siding & Flashing
                        <h3 style="background-image: url('images/Siding/Chimney New Flashing.jpg'); background-size: cover">
                    &nbsp;
                        </h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="description">Painted in Satin Finish
                        <h3 style="background-image: url('images/Siding/Chimney Cedar New Paint.jpg'); background-size: cover">
                    &nbsp;
                        </h3>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </section>
        </main>
        <footer>
        </footer>
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
        <script src="slick/slick.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $('.slider-for').slick({
                slidesToScroll: 1,
                autoplay: true,
                autoplaySpeed: 4000,
                arrows: true,
                fade: true,
                asNavFor: '.slider-nav'        /* the child Nav bar */
            });
            $('.slider-nav').slick({
                /* the Nav display with thumbnails */                slidesToShow: 3,
                slidesToScroll: 1,
                asNavFor: '.slider-for', /* the parent slider */
                dots: false,
                focusOnSelect: true,
                arrows: false,
                infinite: true
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you create a fiddle on jsfiddle.net?

Comment: Aggreed with @ChandraShekhar Can you share the snippet in jsfiddle?

Comment: remove infinite:true on the .slider-nav and give a try

Comment: Removing infinite:true had no effect on the behavior

Comment: In setting this up on jsfiddle, I changed the slick.min.js file from my 1.8.1 to 1.9 and it started working as expected, so it must have been fixed in the newest version which I thought I had, thanks!

Answer (score -2):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.js"> 
</script>
<title>Untitled</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.5.9/slick.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.5.9/slick-theme.min.css"/>
<style>
.main {
  font-family:Arial;
  width:500px;
  display:block;
  margin:0 auto;
}
.description {
    background: #fff;
    color: black;
    font-size: 20px;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 2%;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
}
.main h3 {
    background: #fff;
    color: black;
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 100px;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 2%;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
}
body {
    background-color: #dfdfdf;
}
</style>

</head>
<body>
    <main>

        <section class="main" align="center">
            <div class="slider slider-for">
                <div><img src="images/Siding/Chimney Rotting Holes.jpg" alt="Chimney with Hardboard Siding Rotting with holes"></div>
                <div><img src="images/Siding/Chimney New Flashing.jpg" alt="Chimney replaced with new hardboard siding, new flashing and new cedar trim boards"></div>
                <div><img src="images/Siding/Chimney Cedar New Paint.jpg" alt="Chimney and cedar trim repainted with Sherwin Williams Exterior Super Paint in a Satin finish"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="slider slider-nav">
                <div class="description">Rotted Siding with Holes<h3 style="background-image: url('images/Siding/Chimney Rotting Holes.jpg'); background-size: cover">&nbsp;</h3></div>
                <div class="description">New Siding & Flashing<h3 style="background-image: url('images/Siding/Chimney New Flashing.jpg'); background-size: cover">&nbsp;</h3></div>
                <div class="description">Painted in Satin Finish<h3 style="background-image: url('images/Siding/Chimney Cedar New Paint.jpg'); background-size: cover">&nbsp;</h3></div>
            </div>
        </section>

  </main>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.5.9/slick.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        $('.slider-for').slick({
            slidesToScroll: 1,
            autoplay: true,
            autoplaySpeed: 4000,
            arrows: true,
            fade: true,
            asNavFor: '.slider-nav'     /* the child Nav bar */
        });
        $('.slider-nav').slick({        /* the Nav display with thumbnails */
            slidesToShow: 2,
            slidesToScroll: 1,
            asNavFor: '.slider-for',    /* the parent slider */
            dots: false,
            focusOnSelect: true,
            arrows: false,
            infinite: true
        });
    </script>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```